# Fİrebase document ref path does not getting datas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a basic firebase question could you help me please?

My firebase like this:
User > doc(userid) > user informations and the other collection posts > doc (doc of posts) > post content etc.

Now I have a collectionGroup:

```
  const postRef = useFirestore().collectionGroup("posts");

  const { status, data } = useFirestoreCollection(postRef);
```

[image]

I want to go back using this collection group.
I mean now we are in posts collection, but i want to go back, so i want to go users section. How can i do this? Usign reference.path maybe?

my code:

```
{data?.docs?.reverse().map((d, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <div className="post__body align-items-center">
                        <div className="post__header">
                          <div
                            className="post__avatar d-flex"
                            style={{
                              padding: "10px",
                              marginLeft: "-10px",
                            }}
                          >
                            <Avatar src={img1} />
                            <h3 className="profile-post-username">
                             {console.log(d.ref.path)}{" "}
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                          <div className="post__headerDescription asd">
                            <div className="">{d.data().content}</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src={d.data().imageURL} alt="" />
                        <div className="post__footer">
                          <FavoriteBorder fontSize="medium" />
                          <Publish fontSize="medium" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr></hr>
                  </>
                );
              })}
```

If we look console, it gives this:

```
users/NXh8KBd3OUQA4s8048ADy1KqKn33/posts/riruD1DedJzSmoM
users/AhFDgUrP0oWRNgexbvM6sOuNMAu2/posts/stsMitLGk8VKwHC
```

Now, using these informations, i want to get users email or users names etc.

here homepage:
[image]

if i do like this it gives users doc id:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

updated codes v2:
Now i create new jsx document. Its names User Infos.
here:

```
const UserInfos = () => {
  const userRef = useFirestore().collection("users");

  const { status, data } = useFirestoreCollection(userRef);

  return (
    <div
      className="post__avatar d-flex"
      style={{
        padding: "10px",
        marginLeft: "-10px",
      }}
    >
      <Avatar src={img1} />
      <h3 className="profile-post-username">
        {data?.docs?.map((index) => index.data().email)}{" "}
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

now, the homepage codes like this:

```
 {data?.docs?.reverse().map((d, index) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <div className="post__body align-items-center">
                        <div className="post__header">
                          <UserInfos/>
                          <div className="post__headerDescription asd">
                            <div className="">{d.data().content}</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src={d.data().imageURL} alt="" />
                        <div className="post__footer">
                          <FavoriteBorder fontSize="medium" />
                          <Publish fontSize="medium" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr></hr>
                  </>
                );
              })}
```

and it's screenshot here:
[image]

firestore structure: (posts is collection)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`parent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) property on the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference):

```
const data = "" // assume this as your querySnapshot

const postUser = data.docs[0].ref.parent.parent
// This should be reference to that post's user.

// To get that user's document
const userDoc = await postUser.get()
```

To get post's user info, you can write a function which takes the document snapshot as param:

```js
async function getUserInfo(reference) {
  const userDoc = await reference.parent.parent.get()
  return userDoc
}

getUserInfo(d.ref)
```

Also take a look at [API call inside React Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623779/api-call-in-render-method-in-react-inside-map)

Ideally I would fetch user documents right after fetching the posts:

```js
const postRef = useFirestore().collectionGroup("posts");

const data = ""  // The querySnapshot
const postDocs = data.docs.map(d => d.data())

const userDocs = await Promise.all(data.docs.map(d => d.ref.parent.parent.get()))

userDocs.forEach((uDoc, i) => {
  postDocs[i] = uDoc.data()
  // Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order in Promise.all()
})
```

Comment: how can i adapt this codes in my code (because my code is map). You can think my code like social media card, every user has posts, i can fecth posts, but i can't fetch posts owner

Comment: @efesahin do you want to fetch documents of owner of all posts?

Comment: i editted my code, look above i shared an image in below. I want to user who posts somethings

Comment: i also add 1 more screenshot. If I do d.ref.parent.parent.id ,then it gives me users doc id, but I want users doc informations like email uid etc

Comment: @efesahin as I mentioned to get the document data you need to run `await d.ref.parent.parent.get()` You are accessing the `id` property and hence getting the doc ID

Comment: yes i can get document id, but i want document properties. When I do d.ref.parent.parent.get().email it gives an error

Comment: @efesahin `.get()` returns a promise. Checkout my update answer. or try `(d.ref.parent.parent.get()).email` inside an async function.

Comment: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @efesahin can you update your question with latest code? I'm not sure where you are running the promise. Also you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436930/async-call-to-api-within-map-function-react and [API call in render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623779/api-call-in-render-method-in-react-inside-map)

Comment: @efesahin try the updated answer, and if this was helpful so far do consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: @efesahinit "it doesn't work" doesn't explain what's going wrong. Please share any error that you get. Besides as per original question, you can access the parent collection.  So it's more JS now.

Comment: So let's think about the other ways. I edit my question, I suppose I found somethings

Comment: @Dharmaraj i updated my question. Now we can see all the users. But i need to just one of them, who owner of the post

Comment: Do you have any reference between post an user? Using the parent property you should get owner of post only.

Comment: I will add screenshot of the firestore

Comment: I'm not sure why I can't see move to chat option in comments.. but in case you got Discord, ping me there from link in my profile maybe .. easier to discuss.

Comment: @Dharmaraj look in below

Comment: we solved like this: const userRef = useFirestore().collection("users").doc(d.ref.parent.parent.id); this is one user document, and when we use this, we should use this code data.data(). After that it gives us the answer